# Disable automatic string to number in JSON in Jersey 2

Tags: json, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am upgrading Jersey 1.x to 2.x. I have a method in a resource class like this:

```
@GET @Path("/getId")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String getId() {
    return "1";
}
```

In Jersey 1, when called the API it returned

> "1"

as expected. However in Jersey 2, it seems to automatically convert the string to a number and when the API is called it returns

> 1

How can I get back the behavior in Jersey 1? I want the ID to remain a string, not a number.

If it helps, when migrating to Jersey 2, I simply changed

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

to

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

I also tried adding

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

or

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but it made no difference.

Comment: Why don't you just add escaped quotes `"\"1\""`

Comment: This is just one of the many resource methods that return a number as a string like this. I don't want to change all of them if possible.

Comment: What server are you using? When you say you tried the XxxFeature, do you also have the dependencies for this feature?

Comment: I would imagine that Jackson, whether version 1.x from Jersey 1.x or Jacskon 2.x from Jersey 2.x would behave the same. So I would gues that the problem is that Jackson is not being used.

Comment: The server is Jetty 9.2. How do I know if I have the dependencies for the features? Everything runs and there's no warning or error.

Comment: The init-params will just ignore the value if the class isn't found. Do you have the jersey-media-json-jackson dependency?

Comment: Yes I do. All the jackson jars are there. If I try to remove one of them I get an exception with class not found so I'm quite sure it's being used.

Comment: Yea I don't know then. I would try to test with the Jackson 1 ObjectMapper and the Jackson 2 ObjectMapper just in a standlone test to see how they output the string. Just to make sure that they behave the same. I'm just assuming that they should. You should confirm. If they do, then for some reason Jackson is not being used on your app. You need to figure out why